# Reset scheduled job after completion

Tags: spring-batch

I have an scheduled job implemented with Spring batch. Right now when it finishes it doesn't start again because it is detected as completed, is it possible to reset its state after completion?

```
@Component
class JobScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private Job job1;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * ?")
    public void launchJob1() throws Exception {
        this.jobLauncher.run(this.job1, new JobParameters());
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Job1Configuration{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
            .start(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.NOT_READY.get()).end()
            .from(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.READY.get()).to(this.step2())
            .next(this.step3())
            .end()
            .build();
    }
}
```

I know I can set a job parameter with the time or the id, but this will launch a new execution every 15 minutes. I want to repeat the same execution until is completed without errors, and then, execute a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't restart your job because you're setting the job status to **COMPLETE** by calling `end()` in `.start(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.NOT_READY.get()).end()`.

You should instead either **fail** the job by calling `.start(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.NOT_READY.get()).fail()`

or **stop** the job by calling `.start(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.NOT_READY.get()).stopAndRestart(step1())`

Those options will mean the job status is either **FAILED** or **STOPPED** instead of **COMPLETE** which means that if you launch the job with the same JobParameters, it will **restart** the previous job execution.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringForStop

To launch the job in a way that handles restarting previous instances or starting a new instance, you could look at how the SimpleJobService in spring-batch-admin does it and modify the launch method slightly for your purposes.  This requires you to specify an incremental job parameter that is used to launch new instances of your job.

https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/service/SimpleJobService.java#L250

```
   @Override
    public JobExecution launch(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters) throws NoSuchJobException,
            JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
            JobParametersInvalidException {

        JobExecution jobExecution = null;

        if (jobLocator.getJobNames().contains(jobName)) {
            Job job = jobLocator.getJob(jobName);

            JobExecution lastJobExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(jobName, jobParameters);
            boolean restart = false;
            if (lastJobExecution != null) {
                BatchStatus status = lastJobExecution.getStatus();
                if (status.isUnsuccessful() && status != BatchStatus.ABANDONED) {
                    restart = true;
                }
            }

            if (job.getJobParametersIncrementer() != null && !restart) {
                jobParameters = job.getJobParametersIncrementer().getNext(jobParameters);
            }

            jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

            if (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
                activeExecutions.add(jobExecution);
            }
        } else {
            if (jsrJobOperator != null) {
//                jobExecution = this.jobExecutionDao
//                        .getJobExecution(jsrJobOperator.start(jobName, jobParameters.toProperties()));
                jobExecution = new JobExecution(jsrJobOperator.start(jobName, jobParameters.toProperties()));
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchJobException(String.format("Unable to find job %s to launch",
                        String.valueOf(jobName)));
            }
        }

        return jobExecution;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I didn't explain myself properly. I know that the job restarts if I set the same JobParameters, my problem is to detect wether the job1 has finished successfully. If the job completed all the steps in the first execution and the status ended as COMPLETE, it should launch a new execution (using different parameters) the next time the method launchJob1 is executed. The question is, can I configure the job to do it automatically or do I have to use a JobOperator and do it manually?

Comment: Take a look to my next comment with the solution I implemented. Thanks.

Comment: Added details on how spring-batch-admin does it which is a cleaner implementation

Comment: Thank you! I prefere the methods they use in the code you pasted. I'm going to implement the incrementer and use the JobRepository instead of the JobOperator, seems to be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with after all the comments:

```
@Component
class JobScheduler extends JobSchedulerLauncher {

    @Autowired
    private Job job1;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * ?")
    public void launchJob1() throws Exception {
        this.launch(this.job1);
    }
}

public abstract class JobSchedulerLauncher {

    @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    public void launch(Job job) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
        JobParametersInvalidException, NoSuchJobException, NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionNotRunningException, JobParametersNotFoundException, UnexpectedJobExecutionException {

        // Get the last instance
        final List<JobInstance> jobInstances = this.jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(job.getName(), 0, 1);
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobInstances)) {
            // Get the last executions
            final List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = this.jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstances.get(0));

            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobExecutions)) {
                final JobExecution lastJobExecution = jobExecutions.get(0);
                if (lastJobExecution.isRunning()) {
                    this.jobOperator.stop(lastJobExecution.getId().longValue());
                    this.jobOperator.abandon(lastJobExecution.getId().longValue());
                } else if (lastJobExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.FAILED) || lastJobExecution.getExitStatus().equals(ExitStatus.STOPPED)) {
                    this.jobOperator.restart(lastJobExecution.getId().longValue());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        this.jobOperator.startNextInstance(job.getName());
    }
}
```

My job now uses an incrementer, based on this one https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#JobParametersIncrementer:

```
@Bean
public Job job1() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
        .incrementer(new CustomJobParameterIncrementor())
        .start(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.NOT_READY.get()).end()
        .from(this.step1()).on(STEP1_STATUS.READY.get()).to(this.step2())
        .next(this.step3())
        .end()
        .build();
}
```

In my case my scheduler won't start 2 instances of the same job at the same time, so if I detect a running job in this code it means that the server restarted leaving the job with status STARTED, that's why I stop it and abandon it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difficulty here comes from mixing scheduling with restartability. I would make each schedule execute a distinct job instance (for example by adding the run time as an identifying job parameter).

Now if a given schedule fails, it could be restarted separately until completion without affecting subsequent schedules. This can be done manually or programmtically in another scheduled method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's not a bad idea, but in my case there are a lot jobs that will execute very often and in the most of the cases they won't do anything becuase there will be several validations avoiding its execution. With this solution the database will be filled with entries of instances that didn't do anything, that's why I prefered to "reuse" the same instance until it does something useful.

Comment: You can't reuse the same job instance. A job instance is designed to run only once to completion. If you don't want to fill your meta-data tables with job instances that do nothing, just don't run them in the first place (for example by doing the validations in the scheduled method to conditionally launch the job instance or not).

Comment: With 'reuse' I meant to 'relaunch' it until it does something. Take a look to my post with the solution I implemented. I thought about adding the validations in the scheduled method, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do it this way (I'm starting to use Spring Batch and I'm still learing how it works and what is possible to achieve). Thank you very much for your help.